# rails 5 unable to deploy with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5

I went and made some changes to my database and models. now when I run:

```
cap production deploy
```

I get an error:

```
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "ideas" already exists
```

If this were on my local computer I would just reset the db:

```
rails db:migrate:reset
```

but since I am using capistrano I don't really know what cap task would help here? If there is one?

I did attempt to use the capistrano-rails-collection gem which has a method

```
cap production rails:rake:db:reset
```

Rails 5 made changes to what you can run in a production environment. So now I get an error like this.

```
  01 rake aborted!
  01 ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
  01 If you are sure you want to continue, run the same command with the environment variable:
  01 DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

I am not clear on how I would run cap with an environment variable so either I need a way to fix the initial error from the deploy command or I need to know how to run a cap task with this environment variable set. Open to other options though.

Comment: What happens if you load a copy of the production database on your local machine and run the migrations there?

Comment: you have a link for how to do that?

Comment: Not off hand, no.  I'd need to know where your production DB backups are stored, what postgres management tool you are using, etc.  But that should be a standard check you run before you deploy any code that involves migrations, to make sure there isn't production data that will crash your migrations.